# Haloperidol synthesis - 1-chloro-4-(prop-1-en-2-yl)benzene with NH4Cl and formaldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry

**However I have no idea how the first two steps work. Especially the first step makes me wonder how the amine and the aldehyde form the 1,3-oxazinane.**

[image]

Suggestions:
Ammonia and formaldehyde form via condensation the imine. 
The imine and formaldehyde form the 1,3-oxazinane, however I looks kinda wrong to me. Moreover, if this is mechanism would be correct, why does the formaldehyde binding to prop-1-en and the imine don't?

[image]

Step 2 probably starts with protonating the oxygen and i think the 1,3-oxazinane cleavage follows after. However how does the methyl group bonds with the other methylene group?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/79050/4945 And again it might be better to ask step 2 as a separate question. Link back to this one for context.